# How can I publish an iPad app from an existing iPhone codebase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, app-store-connect

I have a rock solid iPhone app and wanted to know how I could get an iPad app out through iTunes Connect.

1. What steps are required in Xcode (or AppCode) to compile the app iPad friendly?
2. What features (like gps) should I pull from the iPhone code base to prevent strange crashing on the iPad?
3. How do I link and publish the iPad app in iTunes Connect so users who search see my app with a + sign in the App Store (assuming this means it's iPhone and iPad friendly)?

And finally, what else should I look out for doing this from a single obj-c codebase?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of porting possible one is universal app (in which a plus sign is shown with your app in itunes) and the other is two device-specific application (in which two targets are created one for iphone and one for ipad and both get released as complete independent apps). Now it depends on you which modal you choose. Yet I ported my apps using the second option as I want user to buy each time for each of his device :). Anyways, solely depends on you, here's a good tutorial for this http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad. I haven't came across any such thing which can crash a similar app on the ipad but might there'd be some. Though there are somethings which I came across that the ipad (ipod too) doesn't have any vibrator available, as my iphone app was using vibration to give some indication, so if you're using it you might need to circumvent it with some alternatives plus your app should support the PortraitUpsideDown orientation. It's weird that APPLE rejected my third ipad app due to this after releasing my first two apps with the similar limitation :).

Comment: the tutorial you linked to was good but it doesn't show how to get it in the app store combined (unless a simple compile to 3.2 and publish is enough) - where in itunesconnect do I push this up as a combined app?

Comment: ya if you'd upgrade your target using universal app then it'd be enough to compile against 3.2 as target SDK. You don't need to tell anything to itunes connect. It figures out itself what are your target devices, iphone, ipad or both. Hope that helps.

Comment: awesome! i'll try that and see if I can get it approved :)